# installing R packages and Rtools

Tags: r, rtools

I was trying to install packages on Rstudio (R 4.0.2) and got this error:
[image]

also, I was trying to install rtools, but got this error:
[image]

how can I deal with it? what should I do in order to be able to download packages?

Comment: Seems like an issue with your user rights. Talk to your admin.

Comment: Or create your own library in a different directory (where you have the needed permissions) and tell R about it (see `help(".libPaths")`).

Comment: It looks like your username is using non-ASCII characters and R is choking on this. Check which encoding R is using. Unfortunately character encodings in R on Windows are a pain …

Comment: @KonradRudolph and you too of course

Comment: @LihiNoam ... I know it's been a while, but ... are you saying that KonradRudolph "is a pain"?!? That seems rather inappropriate, especially considering that comment to me seems rather factual and non-judgemental.